# module build failed : Custom service is not part of compilation . please make sure it is in your tsconfig

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

I am getting this error while importing custom service in my component file. This service is working perfectly on other component files but dont know why its giving error here.
here is my code of cusom service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, 
HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { GlobalConstants } from "../../shared//constants/global.constant";
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { environment } from  '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class WarehouseService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
console.log('warehouse service')
}
 AddWarehouse(obj):Observable<any>{
return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/Warehouse/save',obj)
 }
getWarehouse(id):Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl+'/api/Warehouse/getById/'+id)
}

deleteWareHouse(id):Observable<any>{
 return 
this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/warehouse/UpdateStatus/'+id+'? 
 status='+true+'&type=1',{})
 }


 }
```

I'm importing this like here

```
   import { WarehouseService } from '../../services/Warehouse.service';
```

but when I made the obj in constructor like this

```
constructor(private spinner: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService,
private globalservice: GlobalService,
private toastr: ToastrService,
private accountService: AccountService,
private router: Router,
public batterySer: BatteryService,
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader, private ngZone: NgZone,
private OrderService: OrderService,
 private WarehouseSer:WarehouseManageService,
 private WarehouseS:WarehouseService  <== this gives error
) {

}
```

it gives me this error
[image: error]

ps this service is working perfectly in other components.

Comment: there are two slashes after shared in GlobalConstants import statement

Comment: that dont matter @Adil

Comment: I think you need to import and provide in the module.ts to which the component belongs to and then import in a specific component.

Comment: is your service  WarehouseService  in another module ? or you have only one

Comment: I already imported and provided  in module file @ChinnaM

Comment: I have multiple modules but I imported WarehouseService in this module @FatehMohamed

Comment: Where you have provided In app.module.ts OR in the module.ts to which the component belongs to

Comment: I provided in only the component belonging to @ChinnaM

Comment: you have to add WarehouseService  to your providers array inside your module.ts

Comment: already imported @FatehMohamed

Comment: Check the configuration in tsconfig.json, mostly this issue comes when the condition to include files is strict, meaning only certain packages are included. Also cli version might be causing this issue, try rc8.

Comment: I made new service and copy the function there import it its working fine , dnt know why its giving error in that service @btreport